FastAPI 'reload' hangs and the application does not restart
I recently added sockets to my application, and since then the reload no longer works but gets stuck in the 'Shutting down' status
Here is a screenshot of the logs in the application.
Capture logs when saving changes:

Here is the content of my socket.py file
from api.configs.logging import logDebug
import socketio

server = socketio.AsyncServer(
    cors_allowed_origins="*",
    async_mode="asgi",
    logger=True,
    engineio_logger=True,
    ping_interval=30,  
    ping_timeout=60,  
)


@server.event
async def connect(sid, x, y):
    logDebug(f"client {sid} connected")
    print(f"client {sid} connected")
    await server.emit("hello", f"you are connected with sid {sid}", to=sid)

Here is part of my __init__.py file the contents of my socket.py file
app = FastAPI(
        title="TRANSIT MASTER API",
        lifespan=LifeSpan,
    )

    # ----mount socket------
    sm = socket.socketio.ASGIApp(socket.server, socketio_path="socket.io")
    app.mount("/ws", sm)
    app.sio = socket.server

Here is the content of my run.py file
from api import createApp, SETTINGS

app = createApp(SETTINGS())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn

    uvicorn.run("run:app", port=80, host="0.0.0.0", reload=True)

Please help me resolve the problem.

Did you try calling the shutdown() method on the Socket.IO server instance? I'm not sure if you realize this, but the Socket.IO server is a completely separate server with its own sets of background tasks. The graceful shutdown option is fairly recent, by the way, so I hope it works within FastAPI, but I have not tested it in this configuration myself.

Yes I tried it but it doesn't give a positive result.

Can you update the question with the code please?
